# MPAndroidChart not working. Failed to add data into PieEntry

Tags: android-studio, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

Failed to add data into PieEntry. All the dependencies and repositories are added correctly. It can run, but the output is not as same as what I code in. I have no idea about how to solve it.

[image]

Main Activity:

```java
private void ShowPieChart() {

    ArrayList<PieEntry> pieEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    String label = "type";

    //initializing data
    Map<String, Integer> typeAmountMap = new HashMap<>();
    typeAmountMap.put("Toys",200);
    typeAmountMap.put("Snacks",230);
    typeAmountMap.put("Clothes",100);
    typeAmountMap.put("Stationary",500);
    typeAmountMap.put("Phone",50);

    //initializing colors for the entries
    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#304567"));
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#309967"));
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#476567"));
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#890567"));
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#a35567"));
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#ff5f67"));
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#3ca567"));

    //input data and fit data into pie chart entry
    for(String type: typeAmountMap.keySet()){
        pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(typeAmountMap.get(type).floatValue(), type));
    }

    PieDataSet pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(pieEntries,label);
    pieDataSet.setValueTextSize(12f);
    pieDataSet.setColors(colors);
    PieData pieData = new PieData(pieDataSet);
    pieData.setDrawValues(true);

    pieChart.setData(pieData);
    pieChart.invalidate();

    pieChart.setUsePercentValues(true);
    pieChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    pieChart.setRotationEnabled(true);
    pieChart.setDragDecelerationFrictionCoef(0.9f);
    pieChart.setRotationAngle(0);

    pieChart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(true); 
    pieChart.animateY(1400, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInOutQuad);
    pieChart.setHoleColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
}
```

XML:

```xml
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:id="@+id/pieChart"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="287dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="144dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="144dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="391dp" />
```